# Using Laravel with a c# backend

Tags: c#, php, laravel

Basicly we want to use Laravel to handle the frontend, but instead of connecting directly with the database through Illuminate, it needs to connect with a C# backend API which returns the data.

However Laravel doesn't seem to support any of this, for example with logging in. Everything has a direct connection with the database.

Does anyone know how to get round to this? I can't seem to find anything about it even being possible.

Comment: From where you get this knowledge "Laravel to handle the frontend"?
for front end we use Html, JS, Jquery

Comment: How are you defining "frontend" and "backend"?

Comment: Laravel is a backend framework (php) , so you either choose C# or Laravel.

Comment: It's a assignment from college. As indeed they are both backend, I got a bit confused.

Comment: do you want to use a source built with C# to feed the laravel data as the database? Or you want to use a C# ORM system instead of eloquent? do you want to use asp.net in a php environment with laravel?

Comment: Laravel (5.3) uses vuejs for frontend you should be able to write a restfull backend in c#

Comment: I would ask for some clarification for your teacher/tutor. Does your laravel app need to communicate with the c# app via the c# api or are you just wanting to use some of the components that are usually (but don't have to be) used with Laravel i.e `Gulp`, `Elixir`, `VueJs` etc.

Comment: @WesselV, since it's an assignment from college, perhaps you should ask your _instructor_ what they mean?

Comment: I've posted an answer purely for the reason that I wanted to share links, I don't expect an up vote, but my answer would have looked really nasty as a comment, not to mention beyond the character limitation.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is somewhat conflicting as Laravel is a backend framework that has capabilities to build HTML components using blade and/or VueJS, you could use Laravel's templating to **construct** your frontend and build the backend with C#, though Laravel's main functionality is empowering and building backend functionality.

As of [Laravel 5.3](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3), [VueJS](http://vuejs.org) is now bundled with Laravel with an example component, though [getting set up](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/frontend) is still a bit of a manual process. Luckily there are several [guides](https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vuejs/episodes/8) which can help you out with this.

In summary, technically speaking, you cannot use Laravel as a frontend, theoretically you can by using its bundled tools:

- Create templates using Blade and/or VueJS
- Create HTTP requests from within your Laravel backend (redundant) or Javascript functions hitting your C# backend.

As others have recommended, ask for further guidance as what your tutor has described doesn't make all that much sense, it can be done using the tools bundled with the Laravel package and not Laravel itself.